# Loading image from a url works fast in one device(Samsung M30) but the same image is taking time to load in another device

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide, image-loading, imageloader

Basically, I'm loading images from url using Glide image loader. Most of the images are loading slowly(nearly a minute) when I tested with Redmi Note 7 pro, Vivo devices but the same images are loaded within 3 seconds in Samsung M30 devices.All the images sizes are less than 3 mb only. I have also tried changing the image loader to Picasso but still the same result.

Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
Glide.with(getActivity()).load(profileDp).into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
@Override
public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {
ivProfilepic.setImageDrawable(resource);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

which version of Glide you are using??

You can use glide to load images without using `onResourceReady` method if you are just loading image on an image view.

like this.

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
.load(profileDp)
.into(ivProfilePic);
```

Comment: Previously I was using an older version 3.7.0. Now I upgraded to 4.10.0 and changed the code as you mentioned but still it takes nearly a minute to load the image. I tried using Fresco library and the issue is fixed but when I upload the APK in Play store it shows me warning saying Device support removed. When I removed fresco library and used any other image loader library Play store is not showing any warning.

Comment: Then u can try UniversalImageLoader Library

Comment: Tried that library also same result.

Comment: which version of SDK you are using in your app??

make sure it supports with Fresco Library